# How to send Password which is stored in Sqlite database into registered Email using Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I made an App, In home page three buttons are present like login, new register, forgot password. For new register four fields are there like name, email, password, confirm password which are stored in SQLite database. After registration, user can login with email and password which is validated with database. My problem is if we click on forgot password, it will ask registered email after click submit button, stored password should go to registered mail id.
Please suggest me.

Comment: Android is not providing you direct send mail without opening composer, so you need to do it using web service.

Comment: for that you have to use use external DB like Fire base .through local DB you can not do that feet.

Comment: Never store your user password in local storage. Instead, use token key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebase Authentication for this.It is the best option for you

documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Example:
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Comment: so I have to change all code or it will work on my forget password separately.

Comment: see once this:https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L69-L69

Comment: Using firebase you can it very easily and it also provides storage option and real database so on...

Comment: Sir, but my compulsion is I have to use SQLite database so can we do this?

Comment: means you are asking about real time database

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data   for save data on cloud     https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data  for retrving stored data even you can build query's

Comment: No, I do not want real time data, I just want to send stored password to registered mail id by sqlite database using android. So is it possible by your solution?

Comment: Because I have to use with sqlite database.

Comment: firebase offers reset password method to reset the password

Comment: link goes to registerd mail id